# Interface for cropping operation: user-resizeable rectangle drawn on image

Tags: ios5, user-interface, uiimageview, controls

I am trying to figure out a way to crop a `UIImage` as it's done in Photoshop Express:

[image]

So basically you just touch and drag the corners to resize the rectangle, then you tap the check button and it crops the image.  Now I have the crop part done -- I made a method that crops an image from a `CGRect` but I am having problems with this resizable rect. Everything I have tried has not worked, and it's making me crazy, because I know it is probably just something easy.  Has anyone ever done anything like this or know of an example on the web?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you have the source code for the custom control you are looking.

http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/bjimagecropper

I recommend you to browse that webpage http://www.cocoacontrols.com, you will find tons of sample code, and most of it has an open license so you can use it in your own app.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Perfect! That looks like it should work.  I will try it out tomorrow!

Answer (score 0):

Made a project that could be useful. Check it out:

https://github.com/noripcord/Crop