# Objective-C Cropping Image by Drawing

Tags: ios, objective-c, drawing, crop

I am new in iOS. I want to crop the image by drawing from user. I search on google for one day and i didn't get the result.
Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Guess what It took few seconds [Link-1](https://github.com/myang-git/iOS-Image-Crop-View) [Link-2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11406573/interface-for-cropping-operation-user-resizeable-rectangle-drawn-on-image)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
  UIImagePickerController *picker=[[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    [picker setAllowsEditing:YES];
    picker.sourceType=UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Then you can get cropping image from

```
  - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
 {
  UIImage *image = [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
 picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{}];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (UIImage *)crop:(CGRect)rect {

    rect = CGRectMake(rect.origin.x*self.scale, 
                      rect.origin.y*self.scale, 
                      rect.size.width*self.scale, 
                      rect.size.height*self.scale);       

    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([self CGImage], rect);
    UIImage *result = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef 
                                          scale:self.scale 
                                    orientation:self.imageOrientation]; 
    CGImageRelease(imageRef);
    return result;
}
```